# Dynamic Text Translation in Input box ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I have a React component in which I have an input box. I want to dynamically change the text inside the input box from English to Arabic. Like I want the text to translate as I type. How can I implement this. This is what I tried and It's not working.

Home.js

```
import React , {useState , useEffect} from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import search from './search.png';
import Footer from "./Footer";
import axios from 'axios';






function Home()
{


    const [to, setTo] = useState('ar');
    const [from, setFrom] = useState('en'); 
    const [input, setInput] = useState('English');
    const [output, setOutput] = useState('');
  
    const translate = () => {
      // curl -X POST "https://libretranslate.de/translate" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "q=hello&source=en&target=es&api_key=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
     
      const params = new URLSearchParams();
      params.append('q', input);
      params.append('source', from);
      params.append('target', to);
      params.append('api_key', 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx');
  
      axios.post('https://libretranslate.de/translate',params, {
        headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
      }).then(res=>{
        console.log(res.data)
        setOutput(res.data.translatedText)
      })
    };
  

    useEffect(() => {

          translate();
      });

      


    return(
        <>
        <div id="searchBox">
            <div id="search">
                <img src={search} alt="search-Button"/>
                <input onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} value={output} id="searchArabic" type="textbox" placeholder='Enter text here.'/>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="copyBox">
            <textarea type="textbox" placeholder='Enter text to copy.' height = "50" />
        </div>




        <Footer/>

        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

It does work sometimes but I can't write anything in the textbox and it does not translate dynamically

Comment: This might help you https://react.i18next.com/, this is a package for translations in react

Answer (score 0):

Your input's value is set to the `output` variable.

This means that whenever the state is updated by the `onInput` event or the `translate()` function firing the DOM is re-rendered with `output` as the value.

First of all you'll need to set the value of the input to `input` to ensure the text you type is displayed:

```
<input onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} value={input} id="searchArabic" type="textbox" placeholder='Enter text here.'/>
```

Then you can move the `output` value to the `<textarea />` below:

```
<textarea type="textbox" value={output} placeholder="Enter text to copy." height={50} />
```

Your translate function fires on every state change at the moment which would result in unnecessary requests. I would recommend only firing it when the `input` state changes. You can do this by setting dependency on the `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  translate();
}, [input]);
```

Comment: I don't want to display the translated text in the bottom textbox, I want the upper textbox text to be translated dynamically as I write in it. Visit www.3arbi.com and try writing something in the search box, I want that functionality.

Comment: In which case you'll need to do a lot of state juggling to show BOTH what's being typed AND what is being translated. Have a look at the [state lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) concepts and decide how best to manage your input entry and callback states.